# Optimizing a where clause using OR and IN statement Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

My SELECT is:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2
WHERE t1.ID=t2.ID
AND (t1.EmpDate IS NULL OR t1.TERMDT > SYSDATE)  -- Item1
AND t2.DIVISION IN ('D1','D2','D3','D4','D5','D6','D7','D8','D9','D10')  --Item2
```

The Item1 and Item2 are causing FULL TABLE Scans on Table1, Table2 respectively.
I have indexed t2.DIVISION.

How do I optimize this?

Can I replace the OR in Item1 with UNION of 2 SELECTs?
Any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: Why do you believe that a full scan is incorrect?  How selective is your predicate on `t2.division` (what fraction of the rows in `t2` have a `division` value that is in your list)?

Comment: 99% of the rows in t2 have those division codes.

Comment: Then why do you believe that using the index on `t2.division` would be more efficient than doing a full table scan?

Comment: The index was add just to see if it would speed up the query.

Comment: Why do you believe that there is a more efficient way to evaluate the query than the one that Oracle has found?  Why do you expect that there is something to optimize here?

Comment: :) The query runs for more than 2+ hours and wanted to find out if there is a way to reduce it.

Comment: What proportion of the rows in T1 are selected by the predicates on that?